# Inner html is not visible

Tags: html

I am new to html and trying to do some small page. I created one main html page and and other html page which includes some menu. I am trying to import it in main html but it is not visible. But I can see inner html when I open it directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
<html lang = "en">

    <head>
         <h1>Demo Page</h1>
    </head>

    <body>
         <link rel="import" href="topmenu.html">
    </body>

</html>
```

my inner html is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" media="screen" />
<div class="topmenu" id="topMenu">
    <a href="aboutMe">About Me</a>
</div>
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed things up. Further I have removed the import, due to compatibility (see: https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topmenu" id="topMenu">
      <a href="aboutMe">About Me</a>
    </div>       
    <h1>Demo Page</h1>      
  </body>
</html>
```

If you do not care about compatibility and you do not care that the import needs javascript, you can use them as rijin described in his answer. I would personally just add a javascript file to the head that writes some stuff in the document, like this:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="topmenu.js"></script>
</head>
```

And the contents of topmenu.js:

```
document.prepend( "<p> mystuff to import </p>" );
```

or with jQuery:

```
$( "body" ).prepend( "<p> mystuff to import </p>" );
```

This is 100% cross browser (if you use jQuery).

Comment: thanks for answer, but still I cannot see the page maybe I have problem with inner html which I added to main question.

Answer (score 0):

Check below plunkr url - you will get some clue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/lLeT0QsYrMx0NqTB1W9y?p=preview

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="topmenu.html">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>First</h1>
    <script>
      var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
      var content = link.import;

      // Grab DOM from warning.html's document.
      var el = content.querySelector('body');

      document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML imports are apparently still in the experimental stage, and not all browsers support this feature; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports).

Google Chrome v. 31 on up support html imports. The OP just needs to make a few changes for the code to work in this browser.  Put META and LINK tags in the HEAD section of an HTML page.  Optionally, you may add an id attribute to the link element to allow the following JavaScript code to easily reference it.

In the JavaScript code, variable content gets assigned an HTML object corresponding to the HTML imported page. The next line assigns the innerHTML of the body element within the HTML object to the current document's body innerHTML attribute.  To avoid demolishing the H1 element and its text "Demo Page", one may use the "+=" operator to append the desired content, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link id="myImportLink" rel="import" href="aboutme2.html">
</head>

    <body>
       <h1>Demo Page</h1>

<script>
var content = document.getElementById('myImportLink').import;
document.body.innerHTML += content.body.innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, the import link refers to a file named "aboutme2.html" to avoid conflicting with another file on my system, but you may call it what you wish.  I suggest that if it is an HTML file then name it something like "aboutMe.html" because a file with an href of "aboutMe" sounds like a text file.  Also, I've embellished the content to show more possibilities.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="topmenu" id="topMenu">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('me').style.visibility='visible'";">About Me</a>
    <div id="me" style="visibility:hidden">
        <ol>
          <li>Cook</li>
          <li>Coder</li>
          <li>Candlestick Maker</li>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

FYI: here's a helpful [article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports) covering HTML imports.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change the file suffixes of your HTML files to `.php` (i.e. `main.php` and `topmenu.php`) and use the following php code to include the `topmenu.php` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
<html lang = "en">

    <head>
         <h1>Demo Page</h1>
    </head>

    <body>
         <?php include "topmenu.php"; ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

You'll have to use a (local) server to properly view the result, but since you are going to publish the page on a "real" server, that shouldn't be a big deal, and that's compatable with definitely *ANY* browser there is, since the inclusion of the second file happens at server level and not in your browser...